# checking values

Tags: excel, vba

```
If UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = "One" Then

    If UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value = "Attentive" Then

    For Each listItem In ws.Range("D1:D56").SpecialCells(xlConstants)

    With Me.ListBox1
    If listItem = "Y" Then .AddItem Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & listItem.Row).Value
    End With

    Next listItem

End If
```

Range A has names.Range C has Values in the form of "One", "Two" and "Three".Range D is Attentive which has values in the form of "Y" and "N".

What this program is doing is:
checking range D1:D56 which has "One" values in Range C and then printing names from column A which has "Y" in it in the listbox.

Now i want to add another entry with "One" therefor i will have to change the range to D57 now and i dont want to repeat this and should be taken in to account by itself and not by manually changing the code.

How can this be done?

Comment: Please remember to mark questions as solved if you get a suitable answer.  Doing so lets other developers know your question has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you just want to make the range you are checking for values **dynamic**.  Because special cells uses the usedrange you can just use:

```
For Each listItem In ws.Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlConstants)
```

Or you can use:

```
For Each listItem In ws.Range("D1", ws.cells(rows.count,"D").end(xlup)).SpecialCells(xlConstants)
```

Based on your comments here is an updated answer:

```
Dim rCell As Range
Dim sValue As String '// Represents your One, Two, Three values
Dim sAttentive As String '// Represents your attentive value

sValue = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value

If UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value = "Attentive" Then
    sAttentive = "Y"
Else
    sAttentive = "N"
End If

For Each rCell In ws.Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlConstants)
    If rCell.Value = sAttentive And rCell.Offset(, -1) = sValue Then
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & listItem.Row).Value
    End If
Next rCell
```

Comment: Your code is working but it is also picking out values which it shouldn't

For example if u choose "Two" in combo box 2 then it is also pulling out values from "one" which has "Y" in the attentive column.

Comment: Your question is a little hard to follow, can you edit your post to show either an example of the data or a screenshot.  I will be able to help you get it solved, if you can clarify your requirements this way.

Comment: First off there are two combo boxes, first one selecting "One", "Two" and "Three", these three values are in column C, i mean many of them, depending on this other combo box which has "attentive" in the column D which is of the form of "Y" and "N". So if i select "One" from first combo box and "attentive" from other it should show all the names from column A having "One" in Column C and "Y" in the attentive column.

Comment: Me.ListBox1.AddItem Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & listItem.Row).Value, This is giving up an error "Object variable or with variable block not set"

Comment: Whoops, try: `Me.ListBox1.AddItem rCell.Offset(, -3).Value`

Comment: thanx a lot Reafidy, now i want to add the marks which are in number format in the column E corresponding to the previous values i selected in another listbox2

Comment: No problem, that will be a different topic so please mark this question as solved and start a new question. I will be happy to help you with it